# How to use Apache Tika on .Net Core?

Tags: .net, .net-core, apache-tika

I need to use .Net Core and create a console app that uses .NET bindings for Apache Tika. Do you guys have any idea on how to proceed?

I found a wrapper called 'TikaOnDotNet' but it only seems to work with .Net Framework but not .Net Core. Is there a way to make this work? Thank you for your response in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the .NET Core framework doesn't have 100% coverage of other .NET Framework types, so it's not compatible on its own.  It would have to be re-written to some extent to work.  Fortunately it's open source :)

Comment: I'm thinking of wrapping the Tika jar file with command line commands in .net core as you can run things like:  *java -jar tika-app.jar -text mydocument.pdf* and just record the output.  Could be a quick fix.